# How to install hadoop on windows

Tags: hadoop, installation

i am trying to install hadoop on my windows machine with the help of following link i.e. Hadoop Tutorial YDN 
http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module3.html

but i am not able to find

- hadoop.job.ugi by clicking on the "Advanced" tab in Eclipse

if anybody knows the solution over it then please reply me.

Your Help Will be Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be careful about the version you use, because according to my experience, using difference version can cause difference problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before and after trying to access the HDFS(in eclipse) and getting an error, I restarted my computer and hadoop.job.ugi showed in the advanced options when I tried again

Answer (score 0):

Try spawning eclipse from Cygwin and it should work fine. It pulls out the information using "whoami" I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I would download the pre-built Windows binaries from here: http://www.barik.net/archive/2015/01/19/172716/

And then follow this official tutorial from Apache: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

You can skip steps 2.3 - 2.6 because those are related to building Hadoop, which you won't need to do if you download the pre-built binaries.

Comment: when I run the start-dfs.cmd command on wondows I am getting this error? 2016-04-27 10:31:10,151 FATAL [main] namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1509)) - Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI for NameNode address (check fs.defaultFS): file:/// has no authority.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:413)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getRpcServerAddress(NameNode.java:464

Comment: I would take a look at this post to see if that fixes your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646308/invalid-uri-for-namenode-address

Comment: I tried all those suggestions, no luck , that is why I ended in your comment box.