# Invalid URI for NameNode address

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I'm trying to set up a `Cloudera` Hadoop cluster, with a master node containing the `namenode`, `secondarynamenode` and `jobtracker`, and two others nodes containing the `datanode` and `tasktracker`. The `Cloudera` version is 4.6, the OS is ubuntu precise x64. Also, this cluster is being created from a AWS instance. `ssh passwordless` has been set as well, `Java` instalation Oracle-7.

Whenever I execute `sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start` I get:

```
2014-05-14 05:08:38,023 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Exception in namenode join
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI for NameNode address (check fs.defaultFS): file:/// has no authority.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getRpcServerAddress(NameNode.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loginAsNameNodeUser(NameNode.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:442)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:621)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1241)
```

My `core-site.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://<master-ip>:8020</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

`mapred-site.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
      <value>hdfs://<master-ip>:8021</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

`hdfs-site.xml`:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.replication</name>
      <value>2</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>dfs.permissions</name>
      <value>false</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

I tried using `public ip`, `private-ip`, `public dns` and `fqdn`, but the result is the same. 
The directory `/etc/hadoop/conf.empty` looks like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2998 Feb 26 10:21 capacity-scheduler.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 1335 Feb 26 10:21 configuration.xsl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    233 Feb 26 10:21 container-executor.cfg
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    287 May 14 05:09 core-site.xml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2445 May 14 05:09 hadoop-env.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 1774 Feb 26 10:21 hadoop-metrics2.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 2490 Feb 26 10:21 hadoop-metrics.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 9196 Feb 26 10:21 hadoop-policy.xml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    332 May 14 05:09 hdfs-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 8735 Feb 26 10:21 log4j.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4113 Feb 26 10:21 mapred-queues.xml.template
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    290 May 14 05:09 mapred-site.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    178 Feb 26 10:21 mapred-site.xml.template
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     12 May 14 05:09 masters
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     29 May 14 05:09 slaves
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 2316 Feb 26 10:21 ssl-client.xml.example
-rw-r--r-- 1 root hadoop 2251 Feb 26 10:21 ssl-server.xml.example
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2513 Feb 26 10:21 yarn-env.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   2262 Feb 26 10:21 yarn-site.xml
```

and `slaves` lists the `ip addresses` of the two slave machines:

```
<slave1-ip>
<slave2-ip>
```

Executing

```
update-alternatives --get-selections | grep hadoop
hadoop-conf                    auto     /etc/hadoop/conf.empty
```

I've done a lot of search, but didn't get anything that could help me fix  my problem. Could someone offer any clue what's going on?

Comment: Ok..I haven't used cloudera much..but,why fs.defaultFS and not fs.default.name? I believe fs.defaultFS is used for HDFS HA.

Comment: @Chandrakant It fails for both `fs.defaultFS` and `fs.default.name`. Furthermore, in the Cloudera page it says `fs.default.name` is deprecated.

Comment: I know that fs.default.name is deprecated in favor of fs.defaultFS . I just didn't see that you were using hadoop-2 in the first place. Looked at the namenode formatting line and realized.

Comment: @Chandrakant Do you have a clue why is the namenode not starting?

Comment: Generally "No authority" means no permission. Have you checked the permissions of the directories namenode is writing to?

Comment: Also can you double check the configuration settings on datanodes and tasktrackers..

Answer (score 16):

I was facing the same issue and fixed by formatting the namenode. Below is the command:

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

core-site.xml entry is :

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

That will definitely solve the problem.

Comment: Had to update my hadoop-3.1.2\etc\hadoop\core-site.xml with this and it worked perfectly in Standalone mode, thanks! Also had to download a DLL from following the links on here and put the DLL in my bin directory: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WindowsProblems

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same thing. I found I had to add a fs.defaultFS property to hdfs-site.xml to match the fs.defaultFS property in core-site.xml:

```
<property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>hdfs://<master-ip>:8020</value>
</property>
```

Once I added this, the secondary namenode started OK.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the HADOOP_PREFIX variable correctly as indicated in the link:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Even i faced the same issue as yours and it got rectified by setting this variable

Answer (score 0):

Might be you had given a wrong syntax for dfs.datanode.data.dir
or dfs.namenode.data.dir in hdfs-site.xml. If you miss / in the  value you will get this error.
Check the syntax of 
        file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/